# How to build a mask (True or False) for consecutive zeroes in a row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and want to create a mask, marking the occurrence of consecutive zeros (3 or more) in it.

I want to mark as True the occurrence of zeros when they happen three or more times consecutively. That is, three or more zeros in a row, without any type of interruption (such as other numbers or NaN). Therefore, the array [0,0,0,1,2,3,4] becomes [True, True, True, False, False, False, False] and the array [0,1,0,2,0,0,0] becomes [False,False,False,False,True,True,True].

The example bellow illustrates better the input and output.

Input:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0       0       0       0       0
0       0       5       0       5
0       0       0       3       3
0       0       0       NaN     0
```

I want the result to be something like

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
True  True  True  True  True
False False False False False
True  True  True  False False
True  True  True  False False
```

Currently I am doing this iterating over the rows, but it is somewhat slow (this dataframe has actually over 1 million rows).

Is there any way I can accomplish this avoiding for loops (iterrows, apply, etc) over the rows?

Thanks!

Comment: And how do you want to *mark* them?

Comment: I want to assign True to the consecutive (3 or more) zeroes and False to anything else (non-zero, NaN, or zeroes that are not consecutive)

Comment: I don't understand how the input produces the output. Maybe showing your working code in the question would help.

Comment: And why are the last three cols in the last row `True`?

Comment: I edited the question. I want this mark True if I find 3 zeros side by side in the same row, and False for anything else.

Comment: I've posted a pure numpy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show a numpy solution and leave it to you to transform to pandas.

```
a = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 5, 0],
    [0, 0, 3],
    [0, 5, 3]]).T
```

First, mask the array and pad the mask with zeros on each row:

```
z = np.zeros((a.shape[0], 1), dtype=bool)
mask = np.concatenate((z, a == 0, z), axis=1)
```

By finding the location where the mask changes value, you can find the length of each run. The padding in the previous step ensures that the first change will be "on" and the last will be "off":

```
locs = np.nonzero(np.diff(mask, axis=1))
```

Now is the slightly tricky part. Normally you would do this in 1D, but here is 2D. However, the padding ensures that your run lengths are still accurate:

```
run_lengths = locs[1][1::2] - locs[1][::2]
```

Now you want to turn off the elements of `mask` that represent runs of fewer than `n=3` elements. With the information you have, it may be easier to just create a new mask directly.

First mask out the runs that are too short:

```
valid_runs = np.flatnonzero(run_lengths >= 3)
```

Then make the output as a `int8`, which we will later view as a `bool`:

```
result = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=np.int8)
```

Set the first element of each valid run to 1, and one past the end to -1:

```
v = 2 * valid_runs
result[locs[0][v], locs[1][v]] = 1
v += 1
v = v[locs[1][v] < result.shape[1]]
result[locs[0][v], locs[1][v]] = -1
```

You can take the cumulative sum of the result in-place, and view it as a boolean mask (since `int8` and `bool_` have the same size):

```
result = np.cumsum(result, axis=1, out=result).view(bool)
```

The final result is:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False]])
```

**TL;DR**

Here is a fully generalized solution that will work across any axis in a multi-dimensional array, with an arbitrary selection for minimum run length (`n`) and number (`k`):

```
def mask_consecutive(a, k=0, n=3, axis=-1):
    shape = list(a.shape)
    shape[axis] = 1;
    z = np.zeros(shape, dtype=bool)
    mask = np.concatenate((z, a == k, z), axis=axis)
    locs = np.argwhere(np.diff(mask, axis=axis))
    run_lengths = locs[1::2, axis] - locs[::2, axis]
    valid_runs = np.flatnonzero(run_lengths >= n)
    result = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=np.int8)
    v = 2 * valid_runs
    result[tuple(locs[v, :].T)] = 1
    v += 1
    v = v[locs[v, axis] < result.shape[axis]]
    result[tuple(locs[v, :].T)] = -1
    return np.cumsum(result, axis=axis, out=result).view(bool)
```

Comment: Nice!  I spent ages trying to get this one, and got so close. Good work!

Comment: @S3DEV. I've updated with a completely general solution that will work across multiple axes

Comment: @S3DEV. Upated yet again to use `np.argwhere` instead of comprehension for generalized solution. I'm glad you got close!